# Azure SQL DW deadlock inside DMS

Tags: azure-synapse

We are getting deadlocks inside DMS at least 30% of the time or more on several of the larger sprocs which truncate and insert several million rows. However, there is only one query running, so I don't see how the deadlock can be my fault:

```
Msg 110802, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
110802;An internal DMS error occurred that caused this operation to fail. Details: Exception: Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.Workers.DmsSqlNativeException, Message: SqlNativeBufferReader.Run, error in OdbcExecuteQuery: SqlState: 40001, NativeError: 1205, 'Error calling: SQLExecDirect(this->GetHstmt(), (SQLWCHAR *)statementText, SQL_NTS), SQL return code: -1 | SQL Error Info: SrvrMsgState: 71, SrvrSeverity: 13,  Error <1>: ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Transaction (Process ID 2265) was deadlocked on lock | generic waitable object resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. | Error calling: pReadConn->ExecuteQuery(statementText, bufferFormat) | state: FFFF, number: 7801, active connections: 120', Connection String: Driver={pdwodbc};APP=TypeC01-DmsNativeReader:DB3\mpdwsvc (13732)-ODBC;Trusted_Connection=yes;AutoTranslate=no;Server=\\.\pipe\DB.3-b6c0a7b26544\sql\query
```

And:

```
110802;An internal DMS error occurred that caused this operation to fail. Details: Exception: Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.Workers.DmsSqlNativeException, Message: SqlNativeBufferReader.Run, error in OdbcExecuteQuery: SqlState: 40001, NativeError: 1205, 'Error calling: SQLExecDirect(this->GetHstmt(), (SQLWCHAR *)statementText, SQL_NTS), SQL return code: -1 | SQL Error Info: SrvrMsgState: 71, SrvrSeverity: 13,  Error <1>: ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Transaction (Process ID 804) was deadlocked on lock | generic waitable object resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. | Error calling: pReadConn->ExecuteQuery(statementText, bufferFormat) | state: FFFF, number: 8106, active connections: 240', Connection String: Driver={pdwodbc};APP=TypeC01-DmsNativeReader:DB38\mpdwsvc (14728)-ODBC;Trusted_Connection=yes;AutoTranslate=no;Server=\\.\pipe\DB.38-b6c0a7b26544\sql\query
```

Does this point at something obvious to check or fix? Or is an Azure support case the best road to a resolution?

**update: support case 115111713384329 is open for this issue**

**update: our SQL DW got a new update March 4, 2016 which supposedly fixes this issue. (I can't reproduce it on demand so I can't say for sure.) If you run "select @@version" then 
10.0.8224.5 or higher should have the fix. If you don't have the fix yet I would imagine opening a support case and requesting it or waiting a few weeks would get you the fix.**

Comment: did the issue get resolved? What was the resolution?

Comment: @JosephIdziorek Support case is still in progress but I think a fix is being deployed fairly soon. Will keep this thread posted.

Comment: @JosephIdziorek I updated the thread with some news

Comment: thank you for the update : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating an Azure support case would be best in this case.  If you can share your stored procedure, that would help us root cause.

Comment: Here's a link with instructions on how to create an Azure support case for SQL DW, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-create-support-ticket/.  If you don't have a support plan which is required to create a ticket, please email us directly at sqldwfeedback@microsoft.com with your server name, database name and the latest timestamp of this error.

Comment: To help you mitigate this issue in the meantime, you can try increasing the SLO (Service Level Objective) of your data warehouse.  Locks and resource contentions are more likely to occur when you run highly concurrent workloads at smaller SLOs such as DW100. Customers have been able to resolve resource deadlock issues by running the workload at a larger SLO.